# Trying to detect when a player has a certain helmet on their head

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a helmet that, when placed on a users head, gives them Night Vision. But for some reason I am having a hard time figuring this out, it seems that it is unable to detect custom tags which is weird because I have had no issues with this whatsoever in the past, but I am a tad bit rusty so it's probably something simple that I have just forgotten.

My code is as follows:

```
execute as @e[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",tag:{NVG:1b}}]}] run effect give @s minecraft:night_vision
```

---

I found the issue, the give command I was using:

```
/give @s leather_helmet{tag:NVG}
```

does not work, does anyone know the proper syntax for this command?

Answer (score 2):

I was stupid, apparently when tagging items with the `/give` command you do not need to specify `tag:`

The correct command for this would be `/give @s leather_helmet{NVG:1b}`